# jQuery add class to specific div

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code that is reading how many items are in a shopping basket, I would like to add a class to a div with the id of #basket_count. I know how to add a class to the span tag were the counter is appearing. Not sure how to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

```
 $('span#ctl00_lblItems').filter(function (index) {
            return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 0;
        }).addClass("green");
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `filter()` (which meant to filter an array of elements), on a jQuery context that is initialized with `#` (id) selector that is bound to return a single element?

Answer (score 26):

same way as you added class to your span

```
$("#basket_count").addClass("your_class");
```