# jQuery How to add a class to a div if another div has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

if any of the webpage elements has **is-open** class, add **open** class to another div. doesn't work

**is-open** is added to div's each time a modal or tab is opened on the page.

```
<script>
if($(".is-open").length){
$(".blur-screen").addClass("open");
} else {
$(".blur-screen").removeClass("open");    
}        
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery add class to specific div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682167/jquery-add-class-to-specific-div)

Comment: Actually I found a solution already. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code in your script runs immediately (before is-open is added to a div, because that only happens if a modal or tab is open, which probably doesn't happen immediately when page is loaded).

what you need to do is to call a function that will check it every time a modal/tab is opened

```
function checkIsOpen() {
  if($(".is-open").length){
    $(".blur-screen").addClass("open");
  } else {
    $(".blur-screen").removeClass("open");    
  }        
}
```

when modal/tab opens:

```
checkIsOpen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if($("div").hasClass('is-open')){
  $(".blur-screen").addClass("open");
} else {
  $(".blur-screen").removeClass("open");    
}
```